# Kolin/Java XmlMapper doesn't honor JAXB annotations while serialization

Tags: java, xml, serialization, annotations, jaxb

I have the following data class which should be serialized

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ImportTravel")
data class ImportTravelDto(

    @XmlElement(name = "ProcessFirstImportdata")
    var processFirstImportdata: AdpDto? = null,

    @XmlElement(name = "ProcessReimportdata")
    var processReImportdata: AdpDto? = null,
)
```

My ObjectMapper looks like this:

```
val mapper = XmlMapper()
mapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
mapper.registerModule(JaxbAnnotationModule())
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
```

I have added the **JaxbAnnotationModule**, from the **com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.14.2** dependency, so that the mapper uses annotations like **XmlRootElement** and **XmlElement**.

My Problem is, that the XML output looks like this:

```
<ImportTravel>
    <processFirstImportdata>
        ...
    </processFirstImportdata>
    <processReImportdata>
        ...
    </processReImportdata>
</ImportTravel>
```

The Mapper honors the **XmlRootElement** annotation but ignores the **XmlElement** annotation.

I don't understand what's wrong, because both annotations are from the same package **javax.xml.bind.annotation**